# Recycler View becomes empty view when the fragment is opened again in Tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-recyclerview

**Fragment A:-**

```
    val pager: ViewPager = v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager)
    val tabs: TabLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.tabs)
    setupViewPager(pager)
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(pager)


private fun setupViewPager(pager: ViewPager) {
  val adapter = activity?.supportFragmentManager?.let { Adapter(it) }

    adapter?.addFragment(FragmentA(), getString(R.string.FragmentA))
    adapter?.addFragment(FragmentB(), getString(R.string.FragmentB))

    pager.adapter = adapter
}
```

**Fragment B:-**

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

```
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_view, container, false)
    listView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView)
    return rootView
}


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    myAdapter = MyAdapter(list)
    listView?.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
    listView?.adapter = myAdapter

}
```

Comment: well yeah, because you're adding another fragment. The code you posted is insufficient though.

Comment: I have added more lines of code where I am adding fragments in ViewPager.

Comment: Load FragmentA and FragmentB in viewpager in another fragment. i.e you are adding FragmentA  inside the FragmentA itself. try to create another FragmentC and setUp your viewpager there.